# how to write unit test for android method and class?

Tags: android, unit-testing

how to write unit test for android method and class?

for example :

```
public int dpToPx (Context context, int dp) {

float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

return Math.round((float) dp * density);

}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing

Comment: use espresso to right android instrumented test to get access of context and android related methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not write Unit test if you are using Android classes. For Android related stuff you need to write `instrumented unit tests`

Reference:
    https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests